# display image in table using html script

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

My approach would be to create an image object in each table row, then set the source to the content of the second column. To do that we need to give the tbody element an id, then iterate thought every child of it.

Check if the image_file_name exists in html table first then show_image in another cell using javascript.I provided 2 images in down blow. First image contains a image folder where I have a list of images and the second image shows the layout of HTML page.

Image Folder (217 images)

[image: Path]

Table (217 rows)
[image: Table]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function displayPictures() {
            //Deaclaring variables
            var tbody, row, imageObject
            //Get the tbody element
            tbody = document.getElementById("tbody >tr >td")
            //For each row
            for (row of tbody) {
                //We create an image object 
                imageObject.onerror = function (e) {
                    this.src = ["/master_project_ideas/imagetocsv/img/MessageMediaPhoto-ID-48.jpg"]
                }
                imageObject.alt = "Not found"

                imageObject = new Image()
                //We set the image source to the 2nd columns content
                imageObject.src = row[2].innerText
                //And finally, we replace the 5th cell's content
                row[5].innerHTML = ""
                row[5].appendChild(imageObject)
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="10" id="dataframe">
        <thead>
            <tr style="text-align: right;">
                <th>Image_id</th>
                <th class="image_file_name"> image_file_name</th>
                <th>Image_Text_output </th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th id="show_image">Show_image</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>/Users/dawitabay/Desktop/master_project_ideas/Image_to_text_with_Tesseract/imagetocsv/img/MessageMediaPhoto-ID-48.jpg
                </td>
                <td>test 2</td>
                <td>24-09-2021 12:20:47</td>
                <td> NaN
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>/Users/dawitabay/Desktop/master_project_ideas/Image_to_text_with_Tesseract/imagetocsv/img/MessageMediaPhoto-ID-48.jpg
                </td>
                <td>test 2</td>
                <td>24-09-2021 12:20:47</td>
                <td>NaN</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have numerous problems in that short snippet of code. Start by checking errors thrown in your browser dev tools console. Always include errors thrown in your questions

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')
    at getColumnIndex (app.js:123)
    at init (app.js:161)

Comment: That's from using `getElementById()` which doesn't take a css selector argument